# Implementing collapsible with nested hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to mimic the task of an accordion with `slideToggle` and panels with bootstrap 3 as a framework. However, my approach this far isn't working this far. My problem is that it's not possible to open any panel, but the first one, and if an inner `panel-heading` is clicked inside the first outer panel, the first panel is completely hidden. I have a panel group with several panels inside, and inside these panels there another panel group with several panels inside. Whenever a panel is opened (toggled the body), I need the other panels to be hidden, if they aren't already.

I created a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk29k/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //when a heading is clicked, a toggle is preformed 
    //and all other toggles are hidden.

    //outside panel
    $('#panelHeadingOuter').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sliderContent = $(this).next('#panelBodyOuter');
        $('#panelBodyOuter').not(sliderContent).hide();
        sliderContent.slideToggle("fast");

        $('#panelBodyOuter').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });

    //inside panel
    $('#panelHeadingInner').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var sliderContent2 = $(this).next('#panelBodyInner');
        $('#panelBodyInner').not(sliderContent2).hide();
        sliderContent2.slideToggle("fast");
        $('#panelBodyInner').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propagating to its parent. Here when you click on the child it executes its own handler and click event bubbles up to its parent and executes its own click event as well resulting in collapsing behavior (since it is opened already).

Try

```
   $('#panelHeadingInner').click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      ....
```

Also it is really a bad idea to duplicate the ids inside the html and attaching events inside another event when you know the elements already exists.

If you change the ids to classes and modifying your JS code to make it more simpler, you can achieve this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $panelOuter = $('.panelBodyOuter'), $panelInner = $('.panelBodyInner');
    $('.panelHeadingOuter').click(function (event) {
        var sliderContent = $(this).next('.panelBodyOuter');
        $panelOuter.not(sliderContent.slideToggle("fast", changeInnerState)).find('.panel-body:visible').addBack().slideUp();
        if(sliderContent.is(':hidden')){
            sliderContent.find('.panel-body:visible').slideUp();
        }
    });
    $('.panelHeadingInner').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var sliderContent = $(this).next('.panelBodyInner');
        $panelInner.not(sliderContent.slideToggle("fast", changeInnerState)).find('.panel-body:visible').addBack().slideUp();;

    });
});
function changeInnerState(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.is(':hidden'))
     $this.find('.panel-body').slideUp();
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THTXR/)**

**Update**

To make this more flexible just rename your class names `panelBodyOuter/Inner` to `panelBody` and `panelHeaderOuter/Inner` to `panelHeader` in your html and then you can just have it flexible enough to add as many nesting as possibly with just one event registration.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panelHeading').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $sliderContent = $(this).next('.panelBody'),
            $panelBody = $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-body');
        $panelBody.not($sliderContent.slideToggle("fast", changeInnerState)).find('.panel-body:visible').addBack().slideUp();
    });

});

function changeInnerState() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':hidden')) $this.find('.panel-body').slideUp();
}
```

and

HTML:

```
      <div class='panel-group'>
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                 <h4 class='panel-title'>Outer1</h4>

            </div>
            <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                <div class='panel-group'>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                             <h4 class='panel-title'>Inner1</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                             <h4 class='panel-title'>Inner2</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                            <p>Pellentesque est odio, hendrerit vitae nisi eget, bibendum porttitor tellus. Aliquam vel luctus mauris.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- panel -->
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                 <h4 class='panel-title'>Outer2</h4>

            </div>
            <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                <div class='panel-group'>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                             <h4 class='panel-title'>Inner3</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                            <p>Duis vitae viverra dui.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading panelHeading'>
                             <h4 class='panel-title'>Inner4</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class='panel-body panelBody' style='display:none;'>
                            <p>Maecenas magna nisi, consequat quis felis sit amet, placerat blandit erat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WNbLU/)**

Comment: So for thanks! However, when the second inner element is clicked, it either does nothing or hides something else?

Comment: yeah, almost like that! However, nothing should be hidden if the panel-body is clicked. Only if the panel-heading is clicked, the panel-body should be hidden. Also, if anything else than the panel-heading is clicked inside the panel-body, the entire panel is hidden.

Comment: no, only the panel-heading should be able to toggle. But yes, it looks really good with the slideup effect :)

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk Then remove that click event on body...  You get the basic idea right? http://jsfiddle.net/9Dm3H/

Comment: yes that works perfectly! Would it be possible to hide the inner panel-body's, if the entire panel-group is hidden?

Comment: I've tried to do the same with some tables, but it doesn't seem to create the same effect when I need to toggle a new table. Could you maybe look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/x2QfL/1/

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk Thats is a problem with table you can workaround by doing this http://jsfiddle.net/8s56d/, but still not perfect as you will do in a div